# Как лучше найти и вывести одинаковые элементы из двух списков?

Tags: java, list, динамические-массивы

Дано два списка строками с целыми числами через пробел. Необходимо вывести уникальные элементы(1 раз - 1 элемент), которые присутствуют и в первом и во втором списке. Элементы необходимо вывести в порядке возрастания. Гарантируется что хотя бы 1 одинаковый элемент в списках есть.

```
    Пример_1
    Ввод:
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    7 8 1 1 1 11 1 1 1 11 1 1 11 1 1 1
    Вывод:
    1 7 8 

    Пример_2
    Ввод:
    0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    Вывод:
    0
```

Написал код, и работает вроде все правильно, первый тест проходит, но почему-то все валится на втором тесте (на нулях). Помогите найти ошибку и поправить!

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String a = sc.nextLine();
    String b = sc.nextLine();
    String[] a1 = a.split(" ");
    ArrayList<Integer> a2 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(a1[i]);
        a2.add(x);
    }
    String[] b1 = b.split(" ");
    ArrayList<Integer> b2 = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < b1.length; i++) {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(b1[i]);
        b2.add(x);
    }

    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a2.size(); i++) {
        Integer x = new Integer(0);
        for (int j = 0; j < b2.size(); j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < result.size(); k++) {
                if (result.get(k) == b2.get(j)) {
                    b2.remove(j);
                    j--;
                    continue;
                }
            }

            if (a2.get(i) == b2.get(j)) {
                result.add(a2.get(i));
                b2.remove(j);
                if (j != 0) j--;
            }
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(result);
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(result.get(i) + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {

    private final static Function<String, Set<Integer>> STRING_TO_SET = s -> 
            Arrays.stream(s.split(" "))
                .map(Integer::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Set<Integer> list1 = STRING_TO_SET.apply(sc.nextLine());
        STRING_TO_SET.apply(sc.nextLine()).stream()
                .filter(s -> list1.contains(s))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

Comment: Все прекрасно работает! Вывод осталось только подредактировать (чтоб не подряд числа шли, а через пробел). Спасибо!

Comment: не за что. думаю с выводом сами справитесь, это уже совсем просто...)

Answer (score 2):

```
class Example {
    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    private static Set<Integer> getInput() {
        return Stream.of(sc.nextLine().split(" "))
                     .map(Integer::valueOf)
                     .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Integer> a = getInput();
        Set<Integer> b = getInput();

        a.retainAll(b);

        String r = a.stream()
                    .sorted()
                    .map(Object::toString)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Кажется, у вас не хватает сортировки перед выводом.

Answer (score 1):

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

String[] s1 = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
String[] s2 = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");

HashSet<String> set1 = new HashSet<>();
HashSet<String> set2 = new HashSet<>();

Collections.addAll(set1,s1);
Collections.addAll(set2,s2);

set1.stream()
    .filter(set2::contains)
    .map(Integer::valueOf)
    .sorted()
    .forEach(s -> System.out.print(s + " "));
```

Comment: Почему-то не проходит тест...странно...

Comment: Тут похоже вся проблема в том, что элементы необходимо вывести в порядке возрастания. HashSet не гарантирует такого порядка, хотя в редких случаях может получиться упорядоченный. Ну и вроде как строки упорядочиваются лексографически, т.е:
1 2 11 - порядок по возрастанию для чисел
1 11 2 - порядок по возрастанию для строковых. Наверное где-то в этом и есть ошибка...

Comment: @СанСаныч дополнил.

Comment: Не работает на некоторых тестах. Я уж и HashSet на TreeSet поменял...и sorted() по Вашей рекомендации добавил...

Comment: вот при таком вводе:

Comment: 1 51 61 51 51 3153 48111 2 121 51 8 1 51 5 1 1 5

Comment: 51 515 1181 1 1 512 215 15 151 8 98 54 545 48 8 78 945191 91

Comment: вывод получается:

Comment: 1 51 8          а должен быть 1 8 51

Comment: А, ну да, там надо к Integer привести, сейчас исправлю.

Comment: Легче сделать это со стримом, поэтому этот вариант и оставлю.

Answer (score 0):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> listFirst = Arrays.asList(1, 14, 14, 2, 5, 6, 9);
        List<Integer> listSecond = Arrays.asList(2, 1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 4, 7, 0);

        getIdenticallyElements(listFirst, listSecond);
    }

    private static void getIdenticallyElements(List<Integer> listFirst, List<Integer> listSecond){

        List<Integer> elementIdenticallyList = new LinkedList<>();
        elementIdenticallyList.addAll(listFirst);

        elementIdenticallyList.retainAll(listSecond);

        System.out.println(elementIdenticallyList.toString());
    }
```